# Server and host in error are different nginx servers, 403 Forbidden

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-22.04

I have two nginx configurations. One is my CDN:

```
server {
    server_name cdn.***.xyz;
    root /var/www/html;
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/cdn.***.xyz/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/cdn.***.xyz/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = cdn.***.xyz) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    server_name cdn.***.xyz;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

And another:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name voting.***.tk;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:12349;
    }
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

When I go to voting.***.tk, I get a 403 Forbidden error. In nginx error logs:
`2023/12/03 10:57:49 [error] 2203089#2203089: *297 directory index of "/var/www/html/" is forbidden, client: 117.216.149.175, server: cdn.***.xyz, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", host: "voting.***.tk"`

Comment: Nginx is using the `server` block containing `server_name cdn.***.xyz;` to process the request. Your browser is connecting using `https` and that is the only `server` block that processes `https` irrespective of "Host" name. Did you type `https` by mistake? Does the parent domain use HSTS headers to force connections to use https in subdomains? Can Nginx see the second configuration? Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all included files and ensure that all expected `server` blocks appear.

Comment: @RichardSmith It forces https. If I'm not using https, it won't connect. So I'm using https. It appears in `nginx -T`.